# How to use list broken Data sources for layers saved in Windows not within an MXD

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, layer-file

I have seen a few question related to listing broken data sources  of layers within an MXD  [MXD list broken links](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19059/use-arcpy-mapping-to-list-broken-data-layers)  See Link  .

I am interested in layers that are not within an MXD. That are sitting within a windows file directory

It seems the syntax is the same , maybe I am passing a file string that is not in the correct format my code is as follows

```
folderPath = r"C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS"

def Get_Layer_files(Folderpath):

    import arcpy,os

    ws = arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    Layer_Container =[]



    Layer_List = arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr")

    for layer in Layer_List:
        Full_Name = folderPath + "\\" + layer
        Layer_Container.append(Full_Name)
    return Layer_Container


import arcpy

my_list = Get_Layer_files(folderPath)


for file in my_list:

    lyrfile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(file)
    lyrlist = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(lyrfile)
    for lyr in lyrlist:

        brokenlist = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources(file)
        for lyr in brokenlist:

            print lyr
```

At the moment I think I am passing my layers file that are saved here

folderPath = r"C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS"

That are each listed as

C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS\a_layer.lyr

C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS\b_layer.lyr

Is this what should be passed into the

```
brokenlist = arcpy.mapping.ListBrokenDataSources('C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS\a_layer.lyr')
```

I am I missing something simple ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a property for layer objects .isBroken, this will return true if the data source is not valid.

Try this

```
folderPath = r"C:\PROJECT\02_USER_FOLDERS\JOHN_SMITH\LAYERS"

def Get_Layer_files(Folderpath):

    import arcpy,os

    ws = arcpy.env.workspace = folderPath
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    Layer_Container =[]



    Layer_List = arcpy.ListFiles("*.lyr")

    for layer in Layer_List:
        Full_Name = folderPath + "\\" + layer
        Layer_Container.append(Full_Name)
    return Layer_Container


import arcpy

my_list = Get_Layer_files(folderPath)
brokenList = []
for file in my_list:
    lyrfile = arcpy.mapping.Layer(file)
    if lyrfile.isBroken:
        brokenList.append(file)
print brokenList
```